# An easy way to change the type of Parsec user state?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm looking for an easy way to combine two parts of ParsecT code that have the same stream and monad, but different user state and outcome.
Essentially a function like this would be nice:

```
withUserState :: u -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s v m a
```

The thing is, that the user state is really helpful in some cases,
but I need different states at different times
and don't want to make the states type any bigger.
Do I have to modify State somehow to achieve this,
or is there already a function for it that I can't find at the moment?

Edit:

I think an alternative would be something like

```
changeUserState :: (u -> v) -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s v m a
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parsec doesn't let you do this directly out of the box, but you can achieve this using Parsec's public API as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Text.Parsec

changeState
  :: forall m s u v a . (Functor m, Monad m)
  => (u -> v)
  -> (v -> u)
  -> ParsecT s u m a
  -> ParsecT s v m a
changeState forward backward = mkPT . transform . runParsecT
  where
    mapState :: forall u v . (u -> v) -> State s u -> State s v
    mapState f st = st { stateUser = f (stateUser st) }

    mapReply :: forall u v . (u -> v) -> Reply s u a -> Reply s v a
    mapReply f (Ok a st err) = Ok a (mapState f st) err
    mapReply _ (Error e) = Error e

    fmap3 = fmap . fmap . fmap

    transform
      :: (State s u -> m (Consumed (m (Reply s u a))))
      -> (State s v -> m (Consumed (m (Reply s v a))))
    transform p st = fmap3 (mapReply forward) (p (mapState backward st))
```

Note that it requires both forward and backward conversion between `u` and `v`. The reason is that first you need to translate your ambient state to the local state, run your inner parser, an then convert back.

`ScopedTypeVariables` and local type signatures are there just for clarity — feel free to remove them if you like.

Comment: Wow - this appears to be exactly what I needed. Also: nice to know that it's possible anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this as the `>>=` operator has the type

```
 ParsecT s u m a -> (a -> ParsecT s u m b) -> ParsecT s u m b
```

and `(<*>)` as

```
 ParsecT s u m (a -> b) -> ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m b
```

The `s` variable is universally quantified, but must match with both terms. Without `>>=` or `<*>` you can use no applicative or monadic functions. This means you'd have absolutely no way to combine any parsers with different states. The best way to do this is just

```
data PotentialStates = State1 ...
                     | State2 ...
                     | State3 ...
```

and then just work with those instead.

Comment: Thanks for the nice argumentation via the types of (>>=) and (<*>). I'll need a minute to test something, but you've probably made me happy already.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful! Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I've tried letting parsers return something like ParsecT s u m (State s u, a) and combine them the way I imagined when running runPT by injecting the state of one parser at the beginning of the next, but replacing the stateUser field. It turned out that this is too much a hell and your answer is pretty much what leads the way in this case. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, it appears I've got to revise my last statement as Roman shows a nice solution to the problem.